# How to display data from multiple tables in View using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

**Student table**
[image: Student table]

**Result table**
[image: Result table]

MY Question: Student table join result table ,but same student name display multiple, so My question I have same student display once

**Model:**

```
public function select(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('result');
 $this->db->join('student', 'result.student_id=student.student_id');
 return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){
  $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'Result',
            'page_name' => 'result/result',
            'result'=>  $this->result_model->select()
        );
$this->load->view('admin/template', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
 <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value['first_name']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $value['mark']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: You use Group By Clause. $this->db->group_by('student.student_id');

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Group By` for display your record as one time

Add This code in your model:

**Model:**

```
<?php

Class Result_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        // Call the CI_Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function select(){
         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('result');
         $this->db->join('student', 'result.student_id=student.student_id');
         $this->db->group_by('student.student_id');
         return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nikunj Rathod     I have create sudent marksheet and above result table in all columns join multiple table but student name,exam name,section name,standard id,subject name all columns duplicate,                                              

And I have to create view Below:  student name, maths,physics,chemestry  below result display    kishan kakadiya,30,40,50

Answer (score 0):

try this model code.

```
public function select(){
$this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->join('student as st', 'st.student_id= re.student_id');
 return $this->db->get('result as re')->result_array();
}
```

Comment: result table in all columns join and display markshit ,but duplicate records return why?

Comment: Marksheet View Below:

Comment: student Name,subject 1,subject 2,...sunject n